# Picasso Fetching Images in Activity, then show them into Fragment's ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso, android-image, imagedownload

I am trying to fetch multiple images in an Activity with FragmentStateAdapter in it.

Then I need to show them into some Fragment's ImageView.
I want to preload them into the cache ( after I receive an API response with the info about images like imageID's)

Do I need to use do something else after .fetch() in Activity and do I need to create again same URL request and then load it into the right image view?

Currently, I am seeing images normally but I guess that they are not preloaded in Activity and I fetch them in the Fragment. I am not sure, how to check it?

***Thank you for your help in advance!***

class FavouriteActivity: - here I want to preload them:

```
    @Subscribe
fun onCoolingImageInfoEvent(coolingEvent: FreezerImageEvent) {

    viewModel.retrieveCoolingImage(coolingEvent.data)

    val applianceID = viewModel.haID
    viewModel.shownCoolingImages.value?.forEach {

        picasso.load("https:/.../api/$applianceID/images/${it.imagekey}")
            ?.fetch() // does I need to do something else?
}
```

This is my adapter in which I have some fragments (for each image different one)

```
class FavouriteAdapter(
   activity: BaseWearActivity,
   private val viewModel: FavouriteViewModel
) : FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {


enum class FavouriteFragmentsEnum(
    val position: Int,
    val fragment: Fragment
) {
    FAVOURITES(0, FavouritesFragment()),
    COOLING_IMAGE(1, CoolingImageFragment(imageIndex = 0)),
    COOLING_IMAGE_2(2, CoolingImageFragment(imageIndex = 1)),
//(...)
```

and Fragment code with images where I need to load already fetched images with Picaso

```
    private fun initPicassoImage(coolingImageData: List<CoolingImageData>) {
       applianceID = viewModel.haID
       imageID = viewModel.getImageIDByIndex(imageIndex)
       picasso.load("https:/.../api/$applianceID/images/$imageID")
        ?.into(current_image, object : Callback {
           // (...)
        } // does I need to do something else? 
       )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like that:

In Activity:

```
   @Subscribe
   fun onCoolingImageInfoEvent(coolingEvent: FreezerImageEvent?) {
        (...)
        viewModel.shownCoolingImages.forEach {

        picasso
          .load("https://(...)/$applianceID/images/${
            viewModel.getImageIDByIndex(index)
          }")
          .priority(Picasso.Priority.HIGH)
          ?.fetch()
        }
    (...) 
   }
```

And in fragment:

```
private fun initPicassoImage() {
    (...)
    val imageUrl = "https://(...)/$applianceID/images/$imageID"
    picasso
        .load(imageUrl)
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
        .into(current_image, object : Callback {

            override fun onSuccess() {
                Log.d("PICASSO", "success load image from memory")
            }

            override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
                //Try again online if cache failed
                picasso
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .into(current_image, object : Callback {

                        override fun onSuccess() {
                            Log.d("PICASSO", "load image from network")
                        }

                        override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
                            Log.e("Picasso", "Could not fetch image")
                        }
                    }); 
            }
        })
}
```

---

Take a Note: as @ocos said, you can check if it loads Image from Memory/Network.

> However, you are fetching images from your server. Picasso may
> invalidate the cache for that URL whenever your server change `http headers` such as `etag`, `document size`, etc in future for that URL.
>
> You may use `picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` to see if an image
> loaded from cache. This adds a little indicator at top left of your
> image.

| Color | Picasso loaded from |
| --- | --- |
| Red | Network |
| Green | Memory |
| Blue | Disk |

Answer (score 1):

Your code seemed to me ok.

However, you are fetching images from your server. Picasso may invalidate the cache for that URL whenever your server change `http headers` such as `etag`, `document size`, etc in future for that URL.

You may use `picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` to see if an image loaded from cache. This adds a little indicator at top left of your image.

| Color | Picasso loaded from |
| --- | --- |
| Red | Network |
| Green | Memory |
| Blue | Disk |

Comment: Thank you, so if I repeat the same request with another image ID, Picasso wouldn't get the cached data of the other images. Because now I have 2 identical requests differ by only 1 parameter .../imageID

Comment: Picasso would check if there is cached image for that URI.
`.../images/444` and `.../images/555` should have their cached images separately. So, you have to make all that image fetch requests.

Comment: I check it and I see always red... why it is always loaded from the network @ocos